# Understanding cnn

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

I'm a computer science student and one of my professors ask me if I can use cnn to make a python application which detect tumors 
can anyone please guide me if that is possible, to understand cnn and apply It on my project

Comment: Welcome to DS SE! Your post is quite broad and should be narrowed to a specific question.  I provided an answer to get you started, but please first research your topic before posting a question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First review the basics of CNNs:

- [high level introduction](https://medium.com/technologymadeeasy/the-best-explanation-of-convolutional-neural-networks-on-the-internet-fbb8b1ad5df8)
- [a more detailed overview](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/)

---

After you gain some intuition, look into [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn) for python implementations.  Depending on what your professor asked of you, explore:

- [semantic segmentation](http://blog.qure.ai/notes/semantic-segmentation-deep-learning-review)
- [object detection](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-for-object-detection-a-comprehensive-review-73930816d8d9)
- or the basic [classification](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-for-image-classification-why-its-challenging-where-we-ve-been-and-what-s-next-93b56948fcef) task

---

There is a plethora of information on this topic, especially for your particular situation:

- [Classification using deep learning neural networks for brain tumors](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2314728817300636)
- [High-Resolution Breast Cancer Screening with
  Multi-View Deep Convolutional Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07047.pdf)
- [Deep Convolutional Neural Networks for Lung Cancer Detection](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2017/pdfs/518.pdf)

---

**Google is your friend!**